# Is there a conflict between GPU rendering and the Firefox Browser in 2.8?

Tags: rendering

So I've noticed this strange behavior where Blender will toggle between taking 6 minutes to render a frame and 1.5 hours for the same frame. I had posted about it here but the moderators took it down.

Answer (score 3):

I finally worked this out. If the Firefox browser is open on my computer, the GPU render time increases from 6 minutes to 1.5 hours per frame. The solution is to close that browser and then the render times drop again. Don't even have to restart Blender. And once the render is running, I can open up Firefox again although it does seem to add about a minute to the render time.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. I'm pretty sure some people will find this info valuable :).